# Interpreting this error message in R

Tags: r

I have the [following](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/mat.csv) matrix

```
mat<-read.csv("mat.csv")
sel<-c(135, 211)
```

I would like to select the rows in 'mat' that correspond to 'sel'

I do it in the following way:

```
subset(mat, mat$V2==c(sel))
```

and I get the following error:

```
Warning message:
In l[, 2] == c(135, 211) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

And also it only selects one of the two.

Comment: Use `%in%` instead of `==`.

Comment: great, thanks! can you very briefly explain when to use which?

Comment: Use `==` if you want to match against a single value or if you have two vectors and want to know which rows are equal. Otherwise use `%in%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (credits go to Roland)

```
mat[mat$V2 %in% sel,]
    X V1  V2 V3 V4  V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
11 11  1 135  2  7 100  2  0  0  0   0
15 15  1 211  5  7 100  2  0  0  0   0
```

from `?'%in%` you can read:

```
    %in% is a more intuitive interface as a binary operator, which returns
a logical vector indicating if there is a match or not for its left operand.
```

If you have a logical vector indicating the matching, then you can use it for indexing and selecting the elements you want. In this case `mat$V2 %in% sel` matches all elements of `mat$V2` that are in `sel` it will give you a logical vector, then using it in `mat[row, col]` you'll get ontly those desired elements as in `mat[mat$V2 %in% sel,]` this means: Give all the columns for those rows which elements meeting the condition `mat$V2 %in% sel`.